# Filtering in XSLT giving error

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bp_list xmlns="http://example.com/2012/03/01/canonical/BusinessPartner">
<total_count>221</total_count>
<bp>
    <bp_id>82721</bp_id>
    <bp_name>bommamv1</bp_name>
    <last_changed_date>2017-01-17T02:52:09</last_changed_date>
    <web_site>
        <id>40485</id>
        <web_site_address>www.bommamv1.com</web_site_address>
        <type>1501</type>
        <is_primary>false</is_primary>
    </web_site>
    <social_compliance_participation_id>9531</social_compliance_participation_id>
    <social_compliance_participation_name>Not currently in Scope</social_compliance_participation_name>
    <private_public_id>9501</private_public_id>
    <private_public_name>Private</private_public_name>
    <year_establishment>2016</year_establishment>
    <contact>
        <id>259832444716</id>
        <first_name>abc</first_name>
        <last_name>mv1</last_name>
        <email>
            <id>230631479</id>
            <email_address>abc@gmail.com</email_address>
            <is_primary>true</is_primary>
        </email>
        <phone>
            <id>327703187</id>
            <phone_number>6014534677</phone_number>
            <extension>101</extension>
            <country_code>1</country_code>
            <display_name>16014534677</display_name>
            <is_primary>true</is_primary>
            <type_id>1201</type_id>
            <type_code>Office</type_code>
        </phone>
        <bp_contact>
            <is_admin_user>true</is_admin_user>
            <is_company_officer>true</is_company_officer>
            <shared_contact_type_id>3100</shared_contact_type_id>
            <shared_contact_type_description>Direct Contact</shared_contact_type_description>
            <job_title>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>Chief Executive Officer</name>
            </job_title>
        </bp_contact>
    </contact>
</bp>
```

I want only those contacts whose `"Is_admin"` is true and in such conditions, I want "Yes" under the admin column. If the `"Is_admin"` is false, I do not want the name in output at all. I tried the following in Oxygen editor :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:ns="http://target.com/2012/03/01/canonical/BusinessPartner">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">bp_name|last_name|first_name|admin_user|job_title|email_address|phone_number_1|phone_number_2|responsibility_name
    <xsl:for-each select="ns:bp_list/ns:bp">
    <xsl:variable name="bp_name" select="ns:bp_name" />
        <xsl:for-each select="ns:contact">
            <xsl:value-of select="$bp_name"/>|<xsl:value-of select="ns:email[ns:is_primary = 'true']/ancestor-or-self::ns:contact/ns:last_name"/>|<xsl:value-of select="ns:email[ns:is_primary = 'true']/ancestor-or-self::ns:contact/ns:first_name"/>|<xsl:for-each select="ns:bp_contact/ns:is_admin_user='true'"><xsl:text>Yes</xsl:text></xsl:for-each>|
            <xsl:for-each select="(ns:bp_contact/ns:job_title)">
                <xsl:value-of select="(ns:name)"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>|<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ns:email/ns:email_address)"/>|<xsl:value-of select="ns:phone[ns:is_primary = 'true']/ns:phone_number" />
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns:phone[ns:is_primary = 'false']/ns:phone_number" />
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>|<xsl:for-each select="(ns:bp_contact/ns:role/ns:responsibility)">
                <xsl:value-of select="(ns:responsibility_name)"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text></xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to handle the above requirement like below (just in case the above code is confusing to read):

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns:bp_contact/ns:is_admin_user='true'">
  <xsl:text>Yes</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>|
```

I am getting an error saying

> The value is not a node set

Please let me know what is wrong here and how can I handle this situation.

I tried adding template in the code:

```
<xsl:template match="ns:bp/ns:contact/ns:bp_contact[ns:is_admin_user = 'true']"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:template>
```

but it did not work. The data is not filetring at all.

Comment: Please add a xslt-1.0 tag to indicate xslt version you are using. Also, your source XML does not have a namespace prefix `ns`, yet you specify it in your XPath expressions. e.g. in the first for-each loop: `<xsl:for-each select="ns:bp_list/ns:bp">`, there is no namespace called `ns` in your source XML, and no element called `bp_list`. Hence the `for-each` loop does not executes. Also, the `select` attribute of `<for-each>` should be a node-set, whereas `select="ns:bp_contact/ns:is_admin_user='true'"` is a boolean expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all `is_admin_user`=`true` `contact`s with the following XPath expression:

```
/contact[bp_contact/is_admin_user='true']
```

An XSLT to copy all the `contact` nodes with the `admin` property would look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/contact[bp_contact/is_admin_user='true']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Looking at your XML I haven't found any evidence that you'd need to apply a namespace on any of the queries.

Comment: A`//` at the start of a match pattern is redundant.